# Yii2 form model saves NULL in the DB

Tags: yii2

So building a simple form but when I try save the form it does not saves the values but only NULL(it will give an error when i change NULL into NOT NULL).

Also every time I save it will add a new row, but I just need 1 row as im saving the values in 1 row.

**db table**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`modalactive` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`modaltimeout` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`activeon` longtext DEFAULT NULL
```

**controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $model = new CmsSettings();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

         return $this->render('index' , ['model' => $model]);

    }else{

        return $this->render('index' , ['model' => $model]);

    }

}
```

**model**

```
class CmsSettings extends ActiveRecord
{
   public $id;
   public $modalactive;
   public $modaltimeout;
   public $activeon;

   public static function tableName()
   {
       return 'cms_settings';
   }

   public function rules(){
     return [
        [['modelactive'], 'required'],
        [['modalactive', 'modaltimeout'], 'integer']
     ];
   }
}
```

**view**

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action'  => yii\helpers\Url::to(['cms-settings/index']),      
]);


echo $form->field($model, 'modalactive');
echo $form->field($model, 'modaltimeout');
echo $form->field($model, 'activeon');

echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('cms', 'save'));

ActiveForm::end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this:

```
   public $id               = 1;
   public $modalactive      = 1;
   public $modaltimeout     = 20000;
   public $activeon;
```

from your model.

After that, add field `activeon` to your `rules()` method. Fields which doesn't exists in `rules()` method are **unsafe**, and won't be processed. Add there `['activeon', 'save']` for testing purposes, if it will work - change it to proper validation.

That's all. ActiveRecord is automatically mapping columns from your table. If you override it - it won't be properly handled. To set default values you should use `default` validator - [Yii2 - Core Default Validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#default)

About multiple saves - you have to load model before using `$model->load()`. Right now, you're creating **new model** every time you save it.

Comment: no I already have tried this, still saves NULL als values. Thanks on the advice for the defaults.

Comment: Propably youre talking about `activeon` field. Add it to rules, fields that doesn't exists in `rules()` method won't be processed at all. Answer updated

Comment: I see you edited answer with removed **values** from **properties in model**, but **you have to delete it totally**. You can't declare properties like that.

Comment: still not working, alle fields are saved as null, when i add a rule with save it will redirect the page to a error(ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Comment: Okay, when I add string (instead of save) it will work, but how can I update the row instead of creating every time a new row?

Comment: What do you mean by `i add string instead of save`? Please update question with actual code, including all modifications

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these properties:

```
public $id               = 1;
public $modalactive = 1;
public $modaltimeout     = 20000;
public $activeon;
```

These will be fetched from database structure and provided as virtual properties by `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong attribute name used in rules.

Please change attribute `modelactive` to `modalactive` in `rules` method in `CmsSettings` Model and remove attributes defined in Model at the top.